# Best structure for list of key-value (integer, string) to be shuffled

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, shuffle, linkedhashmap

I need to implement a structure in Java that is a key-value list (of types Integer-String) and I want to shuffle it.

Basically, I would like to do something like that.

```
    public LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> getQuestionOptionsMap(){

    LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>  shuffle = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> ();

    if (answer1 != null)
        shuffle.put(new Integer(1), answer1);
    if (answer2 != null)
        shuffle.put(new Integer(2), answer2);
    if (answer3 != null)
        shuffle.put(new Integer(3), answer3);
    if (answer4 != null) 
        shuffle.put(new Integer(4), answer4);

    Collections.shuffle(shuffle);
    return shuffle;
}
```

However, HashMap cannot be shuffled.

I could randomly get a key from the hashmap, and then return the linked element, but I'm sure this is not the best solution for my problem.

Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DO you want the integer as a key or String as the key as you have it both ways in  the code.  You need a List if you want to shuffle.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I corrected my code above.
Key is the integer, value is the string (the text of my answer).

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289222/how-to-shuffle-key-value-pairs

Comment: Thanks I saw that thread, but I don't want to modify keys and values.
I just want to get a pair (key-value) randomly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a `Pair` class, that holds both the `Integer` and the `String` and then add multiple `Pair` objects to a List, which will be shuffled.

```
public class Pair {
  private Integer integer;

  private String string;

  //accessors
}
```

Then:

```
List<Pair> list = new ArrayList<Pair>();
//...add some Pair objects to the list
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Comment: Then you won't get HashMap's O(1) lookup though.

Comment: Thanks, I chose this solution, implementing my Pair class as a class inside my main Class.

Answer (score 8):

You can keep the Map.  The Map is designed to be looked up by key so I suggest you have a list of shuffled keys.

```
public Map<Integer, String> getQuestionOptionsMap() {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] answers = {null, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4};
    for (int i = 1; i < answers.length; i++)
        if (answers[i] != null)
            map.put(i, answers[i]);
    List<Integer> order = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    Collections.shuffle(order);
    Map<Integer, String> shuffled = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Integer key : order)
        shuffled.put(key, map.get(key));
    return shuffled;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could keep a separate `List` of the keyvalues, shuffle that and use it to access the `HashMap`.

```
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());
Collections.shuffle(keys);
for(Integer i : keys)
    map.get(i);     // Gets the values in the shuffled order
```

Comment: Yes that's what I wrote at the end of my question, but I wasn't sure was the best option.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hashtable<Integer, String>
```

As an alternative to less convenient and effective `List<SomePairClass<Integer, String>>`

Comment: Maybe a few explanations would be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum` to achieve this, example

```
package device.packet.data;

public enum TLVList {
    
    SpeedingAlarm(0x1001, 3, Short.class),
    LowVoltageAlarm(0x1002, 3, Short.class),
    OBDCommunicationError(0x1015, 3, Short.class),
    IgnitionOn(0x1016, 3, Short.class),
    IgnitionOff(0x1017, 3, Short.class),
    MILAlarm(0x1018, 3, Short.class),
    UnlockAlarm(0x1019, 3, Short.class),
    NoCardPresented(0x101A, 3, Short.class),
    HiddenCommand(0x101B, 3, Short.class),
    Vibration(0x101C, 3, Short.class),
    DoorOpened(0x101D, 3, Short.class);
    
    private int tagFlagHex;
    private int length;
    private Class aClass;

    public int gettagFlagHex() {
        return tagFlagHex;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public Class getClassType() {
        return aClass;
    }

    TLVList(int tagFlagHex, int length, Class aClass) {

        this.tagFlagHex = tagFlagHex;
        this.length = length;
        this.aClass = aClass;
    }

    public static TLVList of(Integer tagFlagHex) {
        for (TLVList tagFlag : TLVList.values()) {
            if(tagFlag.tagFlagHex == tagFlagHex) return tagFlag;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.