# Check if flag is True or False from value passed as String java

Tags: java

Say I have an array of string items, `{"item1", "item2", "item3"}`
and some Boolean values named the same:

```
Boolean item1 = true
Boolean item2 = true
Boolean item3 = false
```

I need to go through the array and stop at a designated spot and be able to return the Boolean value of the item corresponding to the string i am at.

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: You should use a hashmap for this, i cant figure out a way to check if a string value is equal to a variable name.

Comment: you could use reflection... But that´s far from how one should implement something like that and the whole base idea seems to not be that good to begin with

Comment: Your question seems to be related already to a part of a planned solution. What is the original problem you try to solve? Maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 2):

Are `item1`, etc. local variables or fields? In the first case there is no way: Java doesn't do dynamic variable names. Use e.g. `Map<String, Boolean>` instead. In the second case you can use [`Class.getDeclaredField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-) method, but it's quite likely there's a better way to achieve your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The easy method:

```
public class BoolArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean result = checkItem("item1");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    //or without using return type print false in sysout
    public static boolean checkItem(String name){

        String items[] = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};
        boolean hasItem[] = {true, true, false};

        if(name.equals("item1")){
            return hasItem[0];
        }else if(name.equals("item2")){
            return hasItem[1];
        }else if(name.equals("item3")){
            return hasItem[2];
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Or you can use advanced methods(like collection API) then you can reduce code lines. You can use `HashTable` `HashMap`, from these you can work with key, value pairs. Or you can use [List with your own custom Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782110/best-structure-for-list-of-key-value-integer-string-to-be-shuffled).

Using `HashTable`:

You can implement this as a method and get specific value as above one.

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
table.put("item1", true);
table.put("item2", true);
table.put("item3", false);

Enumeration e = table.keys();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
  String key = (String) e.nextElement();
  System.out.println(key + " : " + table.get(key));
}
```

Comment: What is array contains 50+ entries, are we supposed to write 50 else-if combinations?

Comment: He didnot mention that but he can use for-each loop. If you need to see I can update the answer

Comment: I just show him a way he can combine with other answer and achieve his task. Also I mention in my answer that he can use advance method saying this:  "then you can reduce code lines" Is it fine @MehrajMalik

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which returns `boolean` :

```
boolean[] b_arr = {true,true,false};
String[]  s_arr = {"I1","I2","I3"};

public boolean check(){
for(int i=0;i<s_arr.length;i++){
    if(logic_to_check_your_condition){
    return b_arr[i];
    }
 }
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While technically possible, it might be better to take a different approach.
For example:

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("item1", true);
map.put("item2", true);
map.put("item3", false);

String[] array = new String[] {"item1","item2","item3"};

for(String item:array){
    //do something with the string

    boolean youNeedToStop = "item2".equals(item); //you mentioned that you want to stop at some point
    if(youNeedToStop){
        System.out.println("Item: " + item);
        System.out.println("Attached Boolean: " + map.get(item));
        break;
    }
}
```

Here we make a map from String to Boolean. Then, whenever you need the boolean that belongs to a given String, you can get it from the map.